# node js error on response methods between server and client

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http, express

Hey im currently working on my first real webpage using node.js

Im using Express, ejs for layout and redis as database. Im trying to send an ajax call from my index page through my client to my server, use the ajax-call there and pass the final json back to my client where i try to render it on the next ejs page.

Ajax:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".search").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/search",
            cache: false,
            data: {ort: "hierundda", activity: "Wandern", datum: "01.09.2015"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert('Success!')
            }
            , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My server route:

```js
rest.post("/search", jsonParser, function(req, res){
   
        
        /*some database action with redis */
        res.json(dataJson);
    });
});
```

My client route:

```js
app.post('/search', jsonParser, function(req,res){
    var test = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    fs.readFile('./filterergebnis.ejs', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, filestring){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            var options = {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                path: '/search',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Length': test.length
                }
            }

            var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    var userdata = JSON.parse(chunk);
                    console.log(userdata);
                    var html = ejs.render(filestring, userdata);
                  
                  //here does the error appear...
                    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
                    res.writeHead(200);
                    res.write(html);
                    res.end();
                });
            });

            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });

            req.write(test);
            req.end();
        }
    });
});
```

This is what the error looks like:
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28225954/stack.png.html

index.ejs is running on default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using conflicting `res` variable names. Check the variable names of the callbacks from `app.post()` and `http.request()`.

If you change to `response` instead, it might work, if there is no other problems:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
  ...
```

Comment: The problem is still appearing. it just chnageg from res.setHeader to response.setHeader

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/endel/fa851d2cc5f5883a2055#file-stackoverflow-32418763-js-L19-L31